# How to create a transparent window with non-transparent child controls (or child windows)?

Tags: windows, winapi, window, transparent

First, I'm working on Win32 with C++.

I have been trying to implement a transparent window with a child window which should remain 100% opaque. It seems that child controls cannot have opacity better(lower) than the parent and if I make my parent 100% transparent then my child control also inherits the transparency.

Code that I use -

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(GetParent(parentWindowHwnd), 0, 0, LWA_COLORKEY, LWA_ALPHA);
```

Any help?

Please also reply if I am not very clear with my question.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this unfortunately, child windows always have the same opacity as their parent. The Google Desktop Toolbar had a neat trick to give the illusion of an opaque textbox on a translucent background. They created two top level windows, one of the background and one for the textbox. Then they set the background window as the owner (not the *parent*) of the texbox. They then set the background as transparent. It's quite a bit of work to get right, but it's the only way to do it without rendering the whole thing yourself using UpdateLayeredWindow.

Comment: Quick question: how to set the background window as the owner of the texbox?

Comment: Just to update, starting with Windows 8 this is not true anymore. Now childs can be layered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm certain you can do it the other way round, i.e. an opaque main window with a transparent child window, so the reverse may also be true. Have you tried **unsetting** the `WS_EX_LAYERED` flag for the *child* window and then redrawing it to make it completely opaque again?

```
// Remove WS_EX_LAYERED from the window styles
SetWindowLong(hChildWnd, 
              GWL_EXSTYLE,
              GetWindowLong(hChildWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & ~WS_EX_LAYERED);

RedrawWindow(hChildWnd, 
             NULL, 
             NULL, 
             RDW_ERASE | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_FRAME | RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
```

The MSDN page on [Layered Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx#layerwin_topic2d) may also help.

Comment: @ManojAwasthi: If it didn't solve your problem, don't accept it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah. Early days when I didn't understand SO enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a child control less transparent than its parent. The usual approach here is to give your window an irregular shape: not a rectangle. This is much older that alpha transparency - Think about a clock application: you can make your window circular if you wanted, even on windows 95.
This could be done using the Windows API function `SetWindowRgn`:
A simple (vb) [example](http://www.xs4all.nl/~rjg70/vbapi/ref/s/setwindowrgn.html)
[Google results](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=windows+api+setwindowrgn)