# Transparent Tooltip Background

Tags: c, winapi, tooltip, transparency

I have 2 regions in a window, each with their own tooltip.
these tooltips are custom drawn by handling the WM_PAINT message (to prevent flicker).

This is the creation of the tooltips:

```
tooltips[MAIN_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd =  CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST,TOOLTIPS_CLASS,0,WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP | TTS_NOFADE,CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,0,0,g_hInst,0);  
tooltips[SECONDARY_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd =   CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST,TOOLTIPS_CLASS,0,WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP | TTS_NOFADE,CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,0,0,g_hInst,0);
```

This is initialisation of the tooltips:

```
if (tooltips[MAIN_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd)
{

    lpfnOldTTProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLong(tooltips[MAIN_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd,
        GWL_WNDPROC, (DWORD) TooltipProc);
    SetWindowLong(tooltips[MAIN_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(tooltips[MAIN_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd,RGB(255,0,0),0,ULW_COLORKEY);
    SendMessage(tooltips[MAIN_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd,CWM_SETWNDPROC,0,(LPARAM)new WNDPROC(lpfnOldTTProc));
}

if (tooltips[SECONDARY_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd)
{

    lpfnOldTTProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLong(tooltips[SECONDARY_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (DWORD) TooltipProc);
    SetWindowLong(tooltips[SECONDARY_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(tooltips[SECONDARY_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd,RGB(255,0,0),0,ULW_COLORKEY);
    SendMessage(tooltips[SECONDARY_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd,CWM_SETWNDPROC,0,(LPARAM)new WNDPROC(lpfnOldTTProc));
}
```

And this is the WM_PAINT of the custom tooltip WNDPROC:

```
 case WM_PAINT:
     {

        const int FRAME_WIDTH = 1;
        const int CORNER_DIAMETER = 10;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd,&ps);
        HDC hMemDC;
        RECT cr;
        GetClientRect(hWnd,&cr);
        hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP memBM = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, cr.right-cr.left, cr.bottom-cr.top);
        HBITMAP hOldBM = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hMemDC,memBM);
        //drawing start [draw to hMemDC]
        {
            FillSolidRect(hMemDC,0,0,cr.right-cr.left,cr.bottom-cr.top,RGB(255,0,0));               
            HPEN hFramePen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID,FRAME_WIDTH,BLACK);
            HBRUSH hBGBrush = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_INFOBK);
            SetTextColor(hMemDC,GetSysColor(COLOR_INFOTEXT));
            SetBkColor(hMemDC,WHITENESS);
            SetBkMode(hMemDC,TRANSPARENT);
            HBRUSH hOldBrush = (HBRUSH) SelectObject(hMemDC,hBGBrush);
            HPEN hOldPen = (HPEN) SelectObject(hMemDC,hFramePen);
            HFONT hOldFont = SelectFont(hMemDC,g_hFonts[FONT_TOOLTIP]);
            RoundRect(hMemDC,cr.left,cr.top,cr.right,cr.bottom,CORNER_DIAMETER,CORNER_DIAMETER);
            RECT textRec = cr;
            textRec.left += FRAME_WIDTH*2;
            textRec.right -= FRAME_WIDTH*2;
            textRec.top += FRAME_WIDTH*2;
            textRec.bottom -= FRAME_WIDTH*2;
            if(hWnd == tooltips[MAIN_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd)
                DrawText(hMemDC,tttBuffer[MAIN_GRAPH_TT],sizeof(tttBuffer),&textRec,DT_LEFT|DT_TOP);
            else if(hWnd == tooltips[SECONDARY_GRAPH_TT].tthWnd)
                DrawText(hMemDC,tttBuffer[SECONDARY_GRAPH_TT],sizeof(tttBuffer),&textRec,DT_LEFT|DT_TOP);
            SelectObject(hMemDC,hOldBrush);
            SelectObject(hMemDC,hOldPen);
            SelectObject(hMemDC,hOldFont);
            DeleteObject(hFramePen);
            DeleteObject(hBGBrush);

        }
        //drawing end
        BitBlt(hdc,
                cr.left,
                cr.top,
                cr.right-cr.left, cr.bottom-cr.top,
                hMemDC,
                0,
                0,
                SRCCOPY);
        SelectObject(hdc,hOldBM);
        DeleteObject(memBM);
        DeleteDC(hMemDC);
        EndPaint(hWnd,&ps);
     }
    break;
```

The problem with these tooltips is, the corners (outside of the round rect) are supposed to be transparent, but i cant seem to get them to dissapear.
I have tried (naívely) to use HOLLOW_BRUSH to paint the background rect, but didnt work, and as you can see from the example i've tried using the layered window approach, again to no avail.

Can anyone help me get transparency for the background of my tooltips?

---

Here is a picture of the tooltip without transparency
[the corners have been recoloured white for visibility -- these are the parts that need to be transparent]
(Text blanked out)
[image: Tooltip without transparency]

Comment: Ugh.  The notion of a transparent tooltip is a very strange one.  It is supposed to be clearly visible against whatever it overlaps so the tip is easily readable.  I suspect you'll need SetWindowRgn().

Comment: the tooltip is ment to be the colour in the picture, its just the corners that need to be transparent (they are rounded)  -- granted the picture isnt very clear, but you should just about be able to make out that they are red.  they are the parts that need transparency.

Comment: the corners are now white for better visibility

Comment: as for SetWindowRgn(), that does seem like a good idea, i'll have to give it a go, and see if i cant create a tooltip from scratch with it. I'd prefer to do it through the tooltips control, but its definately worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SetWindowRgn` to make parts of a window transparent (create a region using `CreateRoundRectRgn`).

Alternatively, you can use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` to use true alpha blending to make parts of the window transparent.

Comment: I wasn't sure the true alpha blend was what I wanted, but I guess if I'm controlling the wm_paint I guess I just ignore the fact the window is supposed to be transparent and paint... I'll give it a go when I can

Comment: SetWindowRgn and CreateRoundRectRgn have done the job, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with controls and transparency, I found that WS_EX_TRANSPARENT exStyle can save you some time. Also, you may want to check out if the tooltip sends a WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message to the main window, if it does you may want to send back a hollow (null) brush handle in response. You may also need to set the background mode to transparent at that point in time, by calling SetBkMode on the hDC the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message provides.

Sorry for not testing any of this, but it works well with static and group controls. The only control up to now I evidenced is unresponsive to this method is the checkbox button, which I was unable to set background transparency for.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the response... I hadn't thought about handling the colour messages... I really should have. And yeah I have tried ws_ex_transparant already with the other styles, although I neglected to mention it...  Will be looking at if passing a hollow brush can help me though

Comment: @Daboyzuk you're welcome. Don't forget about setting the background mode as well

Comment: sorry for the delay on the response, it seems (unless i'm doing something wrong, or something to block them) tool tips don't actually receive any of the WM_CTLCOLOR messages, which i find a bit odd.

Comment: @Daboyzuk it's allright. IDK, that's nothing odd. It's a rather known and sad fact that common controls in winapi are odd as hell. Just like the checkbox example I mentioned above. One stupid question, are you sure you waited for them in the correct parent window?

Comment: yep, i'm rather sure. i'm not infallible, but I just double checked and i'm still not getting any CTLCOLOR (+ friends) messages for the tooltips.

Comment: @Daboyzuk try looking [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785332/how-to-create-a-transparent-window-with-non-transparent-child-controls-or-child), maybe it can put some gears in motion.